# How could I improve the speed of my algorithm, even by the slightest amount

Tags: python, performance, dictionary, tuples

How can I improve the speed of my algorithm, even by the slightest amount.
For the reason I made this I don't actually care about speed in the slightest, but I'm wondering what I could change if I did. Even more than pointing out specific things to change, what I really want to know is how you know that there's a more efficient way and how that way works. Basically, what is the track to follow if you want to learn how the low level stuff works so that you can write better code at the higher level.

```
def decode_all(ob):
    if(type(ob)==list):
        for i in range(len(ob)):
            ob[i] = decode_all(ob[i])
    if(type(ob)==dict):
        for i in ob.copy():
            ob[i] = decode_all(ob[i])
            if(type(i)==bytes):
                ob[i.decode()] = ob[i]
                ob.pop(i)
    if(type(ob)==tuple):
        new_ob = []
        for i in ob:
            new_ob.append(decode_all(i))
        ob = tuple(new_ob)
    if(type(ob)==bytes):
        return ob.decode()
    return ob
```

Comment: First of all, don't use only `if` statements. Otherwise every `if` is going to be checked every time. Use `elif`s instead.

Comment: I make the copy to prevent the dictionary keys changing error because if there are byte keys in the dictionary I need to replace them with string counterparts. It does seem like .keys() would be faster though.

Comment: Python is slow. If performance is really important, just write in C (Python has good language bindings) or use some low-level-backed libraries (numpy is really famous, but there are tensorflow/keras/numba too, depends on what you need) // popular task-specific optimized libraries  -- also remember to benchmark it yourself... -- on the other hand, list comprehension is probably faster but that's just learning to write idiomatic Python code, not really related to performance.

Comment: Make sure you order your if or if-else statements so that the highest probability object type is the earliest tested for.   You want to have the fewest False tests (multiple compares) on the average.

Comment: Note: your function may modify `ob` in place (both `dict` and `list` types are modified). If that is the intention, be sure to put a big "side effects" warning in your docstring.

Answer (score 4):

Modified code:

```
def decode_all(ob):
    if isinstance(ob, list):
        return [decode_all(e) for e in ob]
    if isinstance(ob, dict):
        return {decode_all(k): decode_all(v) for k, v in ob.items()}
    if isinstance(ob, tuple):
        return tuple([decode_all(e) for e in ob])
    if isinstance(ob, bytes):
        return ob.decode()
    return ob
```

Usually, I agree with the use of `if ... elif ... elif ...`, but in this case, it's simpler to just return the result right away.

Some notes:

1. No side effects: nothing in `ob` or any of its components (at whatever depth) is modified; all new collections and elements are returned, at some (slight) performance cost for their allocation.
2. Use `isinstance()`, not `if type(x) == y` (just a good habit, no particular advantage here with base types).
3. Use list and dict comprehensions; far simpler, no fear of changing the original, and essentially pythonic.
4. No need to handle the case where dict keys would be bytes: use your own function instead.
5. `tuple([x for x in list_])` is *slightly* faster than `tuple(x for x in list_)`, I learned recently.

Some alternatives:

1. If you prefer `if ... elif ...`:

```
def decode_all(ob):
    if isinstance(ob, list):
        ob = [decode_all(e) for e in ob]
    elif isinstance(ob, dict):
        ob = {decode_all(k): decode_all(v) for k, v in ob.items()}
    elif isinstance(ob, tuple):
        ob = tuple(decode_all(e) for e in ob)
    elif isinstance(ob, bytes):
        ob = ob.decode()
    return ob
```

2. Fastest (but a bit opaque):

```
def _fun_bytes(ob):
    return ob.decode()

def _fun_list(ob):
    return [decode_all(e) for e in ob]

def _fun_dict(ob):
    return {decode_all(k): decode_all(v) for k, v in ob.items()}

def _fun_tuple(ob):
    return tuple([decode_all(e) for e in ob])

def _identity(ob):
    return ob

fun_dict = {
    bytes: _fun_bytes,
    list: _fun_list,
    dict: _fun_dict,
    tuple: _fun_tuple,
}

def decode_all(ob):
    return fun_dict.get(type(ob), _identity)(ob)
```

3. Most extensible (you can add various `.register` in various areas in your codebase, e.g. to handle new types):

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def decode_all(ob):
    return ob

@decode_all.register
def _(ob: bytes):
    return ob.decode()

@decode_all.register
def _(ob: list):
    return [decode_all(e) for e in ob]

@decode_all.register
def _(ob: dict):
    return {decode_all(k): decode_all(v) for k, v in ob.items()}

@decode_all.register
def _(ob: tuple):
    return tuple([decode_all(e) for e in ob])
```

Comment: @Guimoute: Nope. Slower (if you are after the last few cycles), as noted in my 4th point.

Comment: why? The OP specifically wants to handle `bytes` keys as well.