# Fastest way to dispatch generic method based on argument type?

Tags: python, generics, dispatch

Say I have a class with a method `.get()` that is meant to be generic, i.e. it does different things dependent on the type of the argument.

I have many possible arguments, therefore I need to implement many possible overrides to this function (maybe about 30 possible argument types).

This particular function `.get()` will be called in a loop billions of times in our code, and I want to make sure that the dispatching logic is implemented to be as fast as possible (the actual content of the `.get()` function will be near instantaneous, so the only possible performance-issue is the dispatch).

What is the **fastest** way to achieve this?

- I know I can use `singledispatch`;
- I can also just put all my functions in a dictionary, and then map each argument to its appropiate method in the dictionary (e.g. by storing the class name in the dictionary as a key);
- It is **not** a possibility to put the 30 overrides on the 30 objects themselves so that it is *their* `.get()` function I call.

Comment: In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65556393/758174) I explored a few options besides `singledispatch` (probably not a comprehensive list). It seems that the `dict` solution (optn 2., which you mention as well) is the fastest (BTW, I used the type as key, not the class name). Happy to hear if there are yet faster ways.

Comment: Did you have some emprirics on how much dict is father than singledispatch, in terms of magnitude for large $N$?

Comment: Yes, I did, but didn't include them as the reproducible setup code is a bit long. Basically, on a deeply nested structure with about 1M terms, I see the `dict` way is ~80% faster than the `singledispatch` method (1.31s vs 2.33s). Note, all methods tried are linear with `n` (so `O(n)`), just the constants are different.